# Where can I get a list of ticker symbols that have stock options?

Tags: united-states, options, online-tools, online-data-source

I would like to examine the option chains of almost every stock that has options.  Is there some sort of stock screener or application that can give me a list of the ticker symbols that have options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may or may not be a complete list but given that the Chicago Board Options Exchange is the largest US options exchange, you might want to check its [directory of equity options](http://www.cboe.com/TradTool/Symbols/SymbolEquity.aspx). They also have a downloadable CSV.

Answer (score 3):

Canada or the US?  I believe the Montreal exchange is the only options exchange in Canada.

Check out:

http://www.m-x.ca/nego_liste_en.php#optionsAction